# okular was not able to locate the font files

Tags: fonts, luatex, okular

I created a dvi with lualatex but okular brings exception that it cannot find fonts.
But nevertheless compilation with dvipdfmx works fine, ok with option -V1.7...

So I think it should be a matter of configuration.
I use texlive.

I did a bit research: xdvi is a bit more chatty and complains:

```
xdvi: Can't find pixel font [/usr/share/fonts/texlive-lm/lmroman12-regular.otf]; using cmr10 instead at 600 dpi.
```

So i watched out for those fonts..
First of all I have `texlive-lm-fonts` installed,
but only `lmroman10-regular` available.

Comment: Imho the only dvi driver that can handle  dvi from lualatex is dvipdfmx and I doubt that popular uses that. Why don't you create a pdf directly?

Comment: @ulrike I think i remember to have compiled into dvi and okular was able to display. 
It just complains about missing fonts, not that it cannot display. 

The question was about why okular does not find fonts. 
THat dvipdfmx can convert to pdf was intended as a hint that the font must be present, 
so okular just does not find them.

Comment: lualatex inserts open type fonts, and old dvi driver can't handle that, they handle only the type1 fonts used by pdflatex.

Comment: I updated a bit. 
I suspect otf means open type font. 
so i have otf fonts but not in the required size. 
I tried also to compile with pdflatex, no difference.

Comment: @user2609605 The problem is not that you are missing fonts. You do have the correct font, otherwise lualatex would have failed already. The problem is that Okular does not support the DVI format extensions used by dvilualatex. The DVI files generated by dvilualatex work *only* with dvisvgmx and dvipdfmx, all other programs will report missing fonts since lualatex uses font formats not supported in other DVI viewers

Comment: @Marcel, ah! pdflatex works, lualatex does not. I wonder.. made a mistake, because i thought i checked before. Thank you.